# Python - Subtracting the Elements of Two Arrays

Tags: python, arrays, math, subtraction

I am new to Python programming and stumbled across this feature of subtracting in python that I can't figure out.  I have two 0/1 arrays, both of size 400.  I want to subtract each element of array one from its corresponding element in array 2.

For example say you have two arrays `A = [0, 1, 1, 0, 0]` and `B = [1, 1, 1, 0, 1]`.
Then I would expect `A - B = [0 - 1, 1 - 1, 1 - 1, 0 - 0, 0 - 1] = [-1, 0, 0, 0, -1]`
However in python I get `[255, 0, 0, 0, 255]`.

Where does this 255 come from and how do I get -1 instead?

Here's some additional information:
The real variables I'm working with are Y and LR_predictions.

Y = array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 1, 1, 1]], dtype=uint8)

LR_predictions = array([0, 1, 1, ..., 0, 1, 0], dtype=uint8)

When I use either Y - LR_predictions or numpy.subtract(Y, LR_predictions)

I get: array([[  0, 255, 255, ...,   1,   0,   1]], dtype=uint8)

Thanks

Comment: What is the code you use to get that result?

Comment: Magic 8-ball says you've got NumPy arrays of dtype uint8, which can't hold negative numbers. Please learn to construct a [mcve]. You're showing us lists, which don't support `A - B` at all.

Comment: @ducminh  I have added some additional information into the questions description above.  Thanks!

Comment: @user2357112 Is this better?  I can't give you all the code here to reproduce it as the data set comes from another, personally created, module, but I believe I've provided enough information.

Answer (score 2):

```
A = [0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
B = [1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
newlist = [e-B[c] for c,e in enumerate(A)]
```

Try a list comprehension. You can't get 255 with regular lists. You should've gotten `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'`

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate this but it looks like the numbers are 8 bit and wrapping some how